# pivoting headers and a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe:

| date | name | value1 | value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | first | 1 | 2 |
| 2021-01-01 | second | 5 | 7 |
| 2021-01-02 | first | 6 | 8 |
| 2021-01-02 | second | 3 | 9 |

And I want to have this one:

| date | values | first | second |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | value1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2021-01-01 | value2 | 2 | 7 |
| 2021-01-02 | value1 | 6 | 3 |
| 2021-01-02 | value2 | 8 | 9 |

How can I do this ? I tried some pivot, transpose and pivot_table, but it doesn't work

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please share your code sample to have fair idea what you have tried and where is the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`df.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) + [`df.stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)

```
(df.pivot(index='date', columns='name', values=['value1', 'value2'])
   .stack(level=0)
   .rename_axis(index=['date', 'values'], columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)


         date  values  first  second
0  2021-01-01  value1      1       5
1  2021-01-01  value2      2       7
2  2021-01-02  value1      6       3
3  2021-01-02  value2      8       9
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `concat`

```
cols = ['date', 'name']

pd.concat({
    k: d.xs(k).rename_axis(None).T.rename_axis('value')
    for k, d in df.set_index(cols).groupby('date')
}, names=['date']).reset_index()

         date   value  first  second
0  2021-01-01  value1      1       5
1  2021-01-01  value2      2       7
2  2021-01-02  value1      6       3
3  2021-01-02  value2      8       9
```

---

#### `melt`

```
(df.melt(['date', 'name'], value_name='v', var_name='value')
   .set_index(['date', 'name', 'value']).v.unstack('name')
   .reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
)

         date   value  first  second
0  2021-01-01  value1      1       5
1  2021-01-01  value2      2       7
2  2021-01-02  value1      6       3
3  2021-01-02  value2      8       9
```

---

#### `for` loop

```
dat = {}
for d, n, v1, v2 in zip(*map(df.get, df)):
    dat.setdefault((d, 'value1'), {}).setdefault(n, v1)
    dat.setdefault((d, 'value2'), {}).setdefault(n, v2)

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dat, 'index').rename_axis(['date', 'value']).reset_index()

         date   value  first  second
0  2021-01-01  value1      1       5
1  2021-01-01  value2      2       7
2  2021-01-02  value1      6       3
3  2021-01-02  value2      8       9
```